# Full database backup using xtrabackup stream

Tags: innodb, mariadb, linux, percona, backup, xtrabackup

I'm new to Percona XtraBackup. I've been trying to perform a full backup stream from my local ( *test server around 600GB* ) to remote server.

I just have some questions and I need guides, and I think this is the best place.

I have this command, which I executed in my local

`innobackupex --user=user --password=password --stream=tar /which/directory/ | pigz | ssh user@10.11.12.13 "cat - > /mybackup/backup.tar.gz"`

My questions are :

- **My log scan is not changing / increasing**

  ```
  >> log scanned up to (270477048535)
  >> log scanned up to (270477048535)
  >> log scanned up to (270477048535)
  >> log scanned up to (270477048535)
  >> log scanned up to (270477048535)
  ```

  I've read a comment before and someone says log scan will not increase if no one is using the database. ( Yes, no one is using the database )
- **It's been running for a while.**

  I've tried to use xtrabackup to a local test server with around 1.7TB and finished in just a few hours. Is this because I'm using stream that's why it is slow?

  What is the purpose of "/which/directory/" in my command? Is it going to store the file in /which/directory/ first and then transfer to my remote server ? Why do I have to specify a directory?
- **No created file on my local server /which/directory/ and to my remote
  server /mybackup/.**

  Am I doing something wrong ?

Is there a much easier way to perform this?

My only goal is to backup my local database to a remote server, I'm doing this stream because I don't have enough disk space to store my backup locally.

I'm using MariaDB 5.5 and Percona XtraBackup 2.2

Answer (score 0):

Just ran into the same problem. As it turned out in this case, the problem was caused by dumping to a NFS volume. Writing the dump to local disk solved this issue.